# Question about Hilbert polynomials and Reduction of ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, hilbert-polynomial

Let $(R, m)$ be a C-M local ring with infinite residue field and
$I$ an $m$-primary ideal. Does there always exist a minimal reduction $J$ of $I$ such that $r_J(I) = n(I) + d$?

Comment: What is $n(I)$?

Comment: $$n(I) = max\{n \in Z : P_I(n) \neq H_I(n)\} $$

Comment: What do those symbols mean?